# Linux bashrc messed up

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I think I messed up my bashrc file adding Java to the path.
None of my commands will work, I cant cd,ls,gedit or sudo.

I tried to manually find my bashrc and change it back but I cant access it because it says I dont have permissions.

How can I reset my bashrc in this state?

Comment: You should be able to use a full path to your editor to edit the file. `/usr/bin/gedit` or similar. Or launch something from an existing shell or X/graphical session.

Comment: Administration question, not a programming question. AskUbuntu might be the place.

Comment: If you truly can't `cd`, then you've messed up something far more important than your `bashrc`. `cd` is a shell builtin and is always available, regardless of your PATH or anything... unless you've somehow managed to get yourself into a restricted shell that doesn't allow `cd`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PATH="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Most things should work now to fix your ~/.bashrc